# How do I add free parameters in Curve Fitting Toolbox (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, parameters, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have obtained a best fit for a dataset with CFT in Matlab.
I now would like to try how good the fit is on another dataset. Can I do this within CFT? I was thinking of plugging in the fit equation from the first dataset with the addition of one free parameter. Does this make sense? And how do I add it in the 'custom equation' box?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataset you want to try out in your workspave as a variable then CFT will be able to use it. I imagine you have x and y data. X remains the same and you change your dataset at the y data option. Just select the other dataset and CFT should fit it with the equation selected.
Now what do you mean with a 'free parameter'? Just post some equations you want to use to fit and I'll show you how to enter that in the custom equation box :)